# Why don't I see one category of treatment in the output of my glmmTMB?

Tags: glmmtmb

I am trying to see the significance of the ground cover after seeding treatments, BA, BG, SC, MX. and compare it with the control plot to see which seeding treatment is better in terms of seeding treatments. I ran glmmTMB with beta family to see the output as the data is not normally distributed.However, in the output I did not see the treatment BA, yet I do have data of this treatment.

I first ran the code `groundcover$treatments<-factor(groundcover$treatments,levels=c("CN","BA","BG","SC","MX"))` to see the significance of the treatments as compared to the control plot.
Second, I ran, `oct.glmm6<-glmmTMB(oct.seeded.gc~treatments+(1|aspect),family = beta_family(),data=groundcover)`, And I see the

```r
summary
summary(oct.glmm6).
```

However, I got the output as:

```
Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          oct.seeded.gc ~ treatments + (1 | aspect)
Data: groundcover

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  -328.9   -319.1    170.5   -340.9       32 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 aspect (Intercept) 0.04482  0.2117  
Number of obs: 38, groups:  aspect, 2

Dispersion parameter for beta family ():  145 

Conditional model:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.6591     0.3793 -14.919   <2e-16 ***
treatmentsBG   0.3168     0.3967   0.799    0.425    
treatmentsSC   0.3565     0.4264   0.836    0.403    
treatmentsMX   0.2952     0.4024   0.734    0.463    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Where is treatmentsBA here?

Comment: You could try `table(groundcover$treatments)` and see whether all levels are actually present in the data. Furthermore, have there been any warnings that may indicate something? Rank-deficient models drop a column, but I think in such cases, the coefficient is still included as `NA`.